# Rally API c# - how to split a story

Tags: rally

My requirement is to split a user story based on a fixed plan (move incomplete and let the user reset the points after).

I've looked through the docs and can't find any reference to this as a function I can call.

My question?
Is there a function that I can pass an array of options to for this to be done?

Or

Do I have to move the story to the new iteration, create a new story in the old iteration, assign the completed tasks to the new story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one-step endpoint to do this.  You'll have to just do the handful of things like you mentioned toward the end of your question.